# Differential equation parameter no periodic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

> Given the equation $y'+\alpha⋅y=\sin(\pi \cdot x)$ find all values of $\alpha$ for which there is no periodic solution.

#### What I have tried:

First I found $y$ and it is $$y = \frac{\alpha \cdot \sin(\pi \cdot x) - \pi \cdot \cos(\pi \cdot x ) }{\pi ^ 2 + \alpha^2 } + c \cdot e^{-αx} $$ where $c_1$ is constant.
Now my idea is to find $y(x)-y(x+T)  \neq 0 $ where T is the period. Is this the approach to take?

Comment: Exponentials are never periodic unless they are constant.  Do that that help?

Comment: Your solution is wrong.  It should be $y = \dfrac{\alpha \sin(\pi x) - \pi \cos(\pi x)}{\pi^2+\alpha^2} + c e^{-ax}$.

Comment: Thanks I have edited it ,but still is this the approach to take after finding the solution ?

Comment: Yes. First identify the period and then evaluate this condition.

Comment: @Paul did you mean that since I have the solution c must be 0 in order to be period ?

Comment: @Tomas either $c=0$ or $\alpha=0$.

Comment: Oh yes ,thank you !